# Other user changes his wrong answer based on information in my answer

Tags: discussion, plagiarism

There was a question about a code snippet that didn't compile because of a missing function.

There was also an answer, saying this function was never there, and explaining why it might not make sense to have it.

The actual problem was that the snippet was compiled with an old compiler, so I posted an answer explaining this. The question and first answer made no mention of compiler versions.

The first answer was then modified to incorporate the same essential information I had posted, and to try to remove contradictions in the original text. It still looks somewhat odd, having contradictory origins and an explanation for something that wasn't true, but is nevertheless voted up and accepted as the answer.

Considering the timeline of events (answers and comments), it is clear to me that the OP and first answerer must have seen my answer and realized the first answer was wrong, and still OP waits until the first answerer modifies his answer, and then accepts that as the answer.

Is this acceptable? Should I comment on this, or just let it go, or... ?

Comment: Contemplating posting answer... "This is bad answer. Really not and answer at all. But I'm not going to fix it even if I now have one!" - not really sure why would you find keeping such answer acceptable instead of edits...

Comment: *OP waits until the first answerer modifies his answer* - Are you sure they were waiting? There's a good chance the OP left and didn't come back until after the other user already changed their answer and accepted it because they saw it first. (It's possible the OP did feel obligated to accept the first answer, I've seen new users say so, but you'll give yourself less heartburn if you don't assume that's what happened.)

Comment: No, the OP commented at a point in time when my answer had been there for quite some time, and quite some time before the other answer was edited. My answer was then the only upvoted, and listed first.

Comment: I'm of course not against people editing their answers if they're wrong, but 1) as @Pekka says "it's common courtesy to mention", and 2) if your answer is dead wrong and someone else quickly slams the right answer on the table, then why the need to edit your answer? I'd rather leave it and let the votes decide which answer is good. (Wild thought: How ridiculous if everybody in here gets in the habit of updating their answers to the correct one in order to gain votes.)

Comment: There are only two real options when you have bad answer - delete and edit. You may want to clarify what kind of edit you would like to see in this case (assuming author is not willing to delete the post).

Comment: @BentTranberg We don't want people leaving answers *they know are wrong* just to let other people decide if it's right or not.  If the author knows that the answer isn't right they should *absolutely* address that, whether they choose to delete the answer or edit it into one that they feel is correct is of course up to them.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's appropriate for someone to correct their answer in response to realizing that it is not correct.  We don't want people to leave bad answers out there just to spite them.  If they realize their mistake and work to correct it *that's great*.

If they're actively plagiarizing another answer, that is of course a problem, but someone realizing, as a result of seeing another answer, that their answer is wrong, and writing a new original answer that they now feel is correct is of course appropriate.

Comment: Agreed. If it was really another answer that gave you the inspiration to correct yours, it's common courtesy to mention that, but demanding it on a site like this is a losing game. There's no way to prove you didn't come up with it independently after thinking about it for a minute.

Comment: I don't have proof, but I'd be naive to think this wasn't an effort by first answerer to save face. But I do agree with you both.

Comment: @BentTranberg Of course it's an effort to save face.  They realized they made a mistake, and they worked to correct it.  It's a problem if they're just copying someone else's answer, but if, as a result of seeing another's answer, they realize their mistake and write their own new correct answer, then that's good.

Comment: It's not a correction, but a 100% turnaround, without making it look like one. I've never seen anybody do something like that on SO before. The good thing is people are upvoting my answer too, and I guess some see the strange way the other answer came out, and understand what happened.